# how write function to calculate the divisor?

Tags: function

I am trying to write function to calculate the divisor but can not complete it .python 3

my code

```
def divisor(x):
    c=0
    for i in range(1, 10000):
        d=x % i
        if d==0:
            c+=1
```

i do not know what to do next .please guide

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def divisor(x):

    c=0
    y=[]
    for i in range ( 1,x+1):

            x % i
            if x % i ==0:
                c+=1
                q=y.append(c)
                q=max(y)
    return q
```